# Dependency library points to device build

Tags: build, xcode4, dependencies, ios-simulator, static-libraries

I've got an XCode 4 project that has an additional dependency project in it. The dependency project creates a static library I need for the major project.

I'm trying to add the library from the Target->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries, choosing the static library in my workspace.

Problem is every time I do that, the build settings "Library Search Paths" is appended a path to the build of the iphoneos build. When I try to compile for simulator, that file is ignored as it not meant for i386 architecture and the build fails.

I've been searching like mad, not understanding what I'm doing differently. Everywhere I look, it seems like XCode should be doing some magic to link simulator with simulator and device with device - But for me it always adds the specific path to either the device or simulator.

(I've tried using two targets to differ them, and that worked, but it's not an ideal solution at all. I have to change  2 targets everytime instead of 1.)

Hope I was understood,

pleeeaaaaase help :)

Oded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague found the answer eventually -

In XCode 4 the default is to build all projects to a shared building folder. Me being fixated with XCode 3, switched it to the old method in which the build folder is in your project folder.

Turns out switching XCode to build in a single unique place, allowed the magic to happen to and to the corresponding builds be built together. I've been told it's exactly what it's meant for, but have no link to the reference.

XCode Menu -> Preferences -> Locations -> Build Location:
- Place build in derived data location (recommended)
- Unique subfolder

Cheers,
Oded.